# Permutation of all the characters when few characters are always together

Tags: algorithm, matlab, combinations, permutation

I am trying to obtain the permutation of all characters in a string lets say 'KIRAN'. I can use :

perms('KIRAN')

This returns a permutation of all the character in the string which factorial(5)=120. Now, I am looking to obtain, the permutation of the string when the characters 'IRA' are always together.

The answer is factorial(3) = 6.

I would like to write a module which returns the permutation of all the characters, where 'IRA' are always together.

Any idea how to programmatically obtain it in Matlab?

Thanks

Comment: Know nothing about Matlab, but is it possible to remove 'RA', permute the rest and insert 'RA' after 'I' into every output string?

Comment: Simple mathematics : You can treat `'IRA'` as a single letter `'X'` and now proceed with `'KXN'` . Display all permutation, replacing `'X'` with `'IRA'`, in output. This won't be hard for you to code in matlab, since you're a [matlab expert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/276859/www-sapnaedu-in)  ;)

Comment: @CiaPan Your intuition is correct and your method is equivalent to Daniel's answer below. (If `I` is not unique in the sequence then you can simply replace `IRA` with some other marker value that is not in the sequence.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x={'K','IRA','N'}
%one permutation per row
y=x(perms(1:numel(x)))
%concatinate rows
y=arrayfun(@(x)[y{x,:}],1:size(y,1),'UniformOutput',false)
```